# What is the best way to display and search in a lot of data in android

Tags: java, android, csv

My application well be displaying over 20.000 meals that is stored in a csv file,

it will then be displaying these meals filtered by data the user puts in.

First a string, and it will only display results with that string in the CSV file, except if the user picks "all"

Then it will be ranked by what matches closest with what the user chooses as: calories, fat, carbs, fiber and protein.

at the moment i have imported it all from the csv file and trying to make a listView with the data, like this example: https://github.com/FoamyGuy/CSVListExample/blob/master/src/com/makemyandroidapp/example/csvlist/CSVAdapter.java

but i'm at a loss on how to display all the data and let it be filtered correctly with user input.

help is appreciated :)

Comment: Have you thought about using a Android SQL-DataBase. It can store a high amount of data and search/filter after given rules. If you are interested, read this: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: huh, i read about it, but i actually haven't thought about using it yet. It definitely seems feasible to store the CSV file in it. do you have any examples of somebody searching and displaying from sqlite based on multiple variables?

Comment: The best way is by using a **database**. A text file is a very bad fpr performance and also very limited in searching/filtering.

Comment: so i should put the data from the csv file into a database?

Comment: yes. You should do that. Before looking for examples, read the link from my first comment.